# Prove that $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ is dense in $C([0,1])$

Tags: general-topology

First some definitions I use to prevent misunderstanding.

For a compact Hausdorff space $X$, we consider the set of scalar-valued functions on $X$: $$C(X):=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}: f \text{ is continuous}\}.$$
There is a metric on $C(X)$: $$d_{\sup}(f,g):=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
The induced topology is called the uniform topology on $C(X)$.

Now my question. I have to prove that $C^{\infty}([0,1])$, the space of real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ which are infinitely many times differentiable, is dense in $C([0,1])$. Now I figured, if I show that $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ is point-seperating, I can use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to say it is dense in $C([0,1])$.

I know that a space is point-seperating if for any $x,y\in X, x\neq y, \exists f\in C^{\infty}([0,1])$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. 
But how do I show this?

Hope someone can help me! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you think of a smooth function $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is injective? This would demonstrate that $C^{\infty}([0, 1])$ separates points.

Comment: Polynomials form a subset of $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ which is dense in $C([0,1])$. You don't need to resort to Stone Weierstrass.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM So if I just say that they form a subset and are dense, then $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ is dense?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese maybe $f(x)=e^x$? or am I thinking totally wrong..

Comment: That is one such function. Another is $f(x) = x$. Either way, for any $x, y \in [0, 1]$ there is $f \in C^{\infty}([0, 1])$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Comment: Alternative approach: Given a continuos function, you can *fold* it with a mollifier function ...

Comment: the piecewise constant functions on $[0;1]$ are dense in $C([0;1])$ and $C^\infty([0;1])$ is dense in the piecewise constant functions on $[0;1]$ (for any of the $||.||_p$ norms)

Comment: @JBIBB Yes, that argument is fine.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right. I think that "convolve" is more common than "fold", at least in English. (In stuff written in English about 70 or 80 years ago I've seen references to the "faltung" of two functions; I have no idea whether it's still called the faltung in German.)

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM But why is that true? I mean, that is one example of real-valued inifinitely many times differential functions.. Is there a theorem that can tell my why?